# Thread Pool with threads having DUPLICATE names

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am learning python multithreading and taking a stab at using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`.

I created two ThreadPoolExecutor functions that use `executor.map()` method.  Both function are identical in that each will create 10 future objects (or threads).  However, one function is passing the `max_worker=5` argument, while the other does not.  Both functions execute another function named 'do_futures' that assigns a name for each thread in the the thread pool using `threading.current_thread().getname()`.

Here is my code:

```
import concurrent.futures
import threading
import time

# timer functions
def start_timer():
    return time.perf_counter()

def total_time(started):
    finished = time.perf_counter()
    return f'Total execution time is {round(finished-started,2)} second(s)'

# assigns name to each thread in a thread pool
def do_futures(seconds):
    print(f'{threading.currentThread().getName()} sleeping begin {seconds} second(s)...')
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return f'{threading.currentThread().getName()} done sleeping for {seconds} seconds.'


def threadpool_exec_map():

    start = start_timer()

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        secs = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3 ,4, 1, 5]
        results = executor.map(do_futures, secs)

        for result in results:
            print(result)

    print(f'{total_time(start)}')

def threadpool_exec_map2(max_workers):
   
    start = start_timer()
    print(f'\n{max_workers = }\n')

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
        secs = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3 ,4, 1, 5]
        results = executor.map(do_futures, secs)

        for result in results:
            print(result)

    print(f'{total_time(start)}')

# ------ main ----------- #
if __name__ == '__main__':

    threadpool_exec_map()               # concurrent.futures ThreadPoolExecutor() - NO max_workers passed
    threadpool_exec_map2(5)              # concurrent.futures ThreadPoolExecutor() - passing (max_workers=5) argument
```

Output for the `threadpool_exec_map()` is as follows (ALL showing UNIQUE names, no issue)

```
hreadPoolExecutor-0_0 sleeping begin 5 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 sleeping begin 4 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 sleeping begin 3 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 sleeping begin 2 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_4 sleeping begin 1 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_5 sleeping begin 2 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_6 sleeping begin 3 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_7 sleeping begin 4 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_8 sleeping begin 1 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_9 sleeping begin 5 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0 done sleeping for 5 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1 done sleeping for 4 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2 done sleeping for 3 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_3 done sleeping for 2 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_4 done sleeping for 1 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_5 done sleeping for 2 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_6 done sleeping for 3 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_7 done sleeping for 4 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_8 done sleeping for 1 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-0_9 done sleeping for 5 seconds.
Total execution time is 5.0 second(s)
```

However, the `threadpool_exec_map2(5)` output below shows that three threads in the threadpool are assigned the same thread name `ThreadPoolExecutor-1_4`:

```
max_workers = 5

ThreadPoolExecutor-1_0 sleeping begin 5 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_1 sleeping begin 4 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_2 sleeping begin 3 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_3 sleeping begin 2 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_4 sleeping begin 1 second(s)...  < original
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_4 sleeping begin 2 second(s)...  < duplicate name
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_3 sleeping begin 3 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_2 sleeping begin 4 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_4 sleeping begin 1 second(s)...  < third thread with same name
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_1 sleeping begin 5 second(s)...
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_0 done sleeping for 5 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_1 done sleeping for 4 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_2 done sleeping for 3 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_3 done sleeping for 2 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_4 done sleeping for 1 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_4 done sleeping for 2 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_3 done sleeping for 3 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_2 done sleeping for 4 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_4 done sleeping for 1 seconds.
ThreadPoolExecutor-1_1 done sleeping for 5 seconds.
Total execution time is 9.01 second(s)
```

When the `do_futures` is called by the first function `threadpool_exec_map()` - which does NOT pass any argument -  it assigns unique names to each thread in the threadpool as expected.

But when `do_futures` is called by the `threadpool_exec_map2(5)` function it assigned three thread with the same name.

I believe passing the `max_workers=5` argument to the `threadpool_exec_map()` function is the culprit, but couldn't explain it from the output.  How could *three threads with the same name* "start sleeping concurrently"?   Shouldn't the first thread with that name  be "completed" first before assigning the same name to the next thread, and so on?

Input appreciated.

Comment: The threads don't have the same name. It's a threadpool.  If max_workers is 5, then it only creates 5 threads, and reuses some of them. It isn't 2 threads with same name, it is the same thread executing multiple times

Comment: Something looks fishy there: All threads start, even though you only configure five workers and none of the first five tasks have finished yet, at least according to the output. Of course, that's explained by the code, but formatting a log entry but not printing it at the time it happens may give you this confusing output.

Answer (score 2):

What you are missing is that `time.sleep` releases the worker thread to do other work. There is no reason to have a CPU thread just idly looping. While your code sleeps, the thread is used to do work elsewhere.

With a threadpool of size 5, it will kick off 5 threads. They all pretty instantly go to sleep, at which point the threads can be used to work on the other jobs (sometimes called tasks). It sleeps again, so can be used a 3rd time, but it is essentially random which of the 5 sleeping threads will be used.

If you want to see it work differently, try doing some work instead of using `sleep`, like calculate fibonacci(50) or something.

Comment: Thank you @Garr for the explanation.  But doing calculation would be calling for using ProcessPoolExecutor instead of ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean about "tasks".   So ThreadPool creates "worker threads" (as they are 'officially' called in python - or 'tasks' as you and I call it).   BTW,  I found in the https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html documentation that indicate that `ThreadPool reuse idle work thread`.

Comment: BTW,  I found in the https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html documentation that indicate that `ThreadPool reuse idle work thread`.   
Also I realized that the `ThreadPoolExecutor-1_4` worker thread sleeps for only 1 second.  So basically  this supports the statement from the documentation that  after  that  worker thread  with the name `ThreadPoolExecutor-1_4`  finishes, ThreadPoolExecutor just reuses that worker thread (and its name) and this is why we are seeing the name repeating a few times.

Comment: a thread is different than a task. A task/job/work is something that needs to be done. a thread is used to get the work done

Comment: I agree, it should be called a "worker thread" in this context, not task.

Comment: depends on what you mean by "it".  Each call to `do_something` is a task. You can have 10 tasks serviced by 5 threads in this case.

Comment: So  the threadpoolExecutor create worker threads, and the function that these work threads execute are called tasks then.  I am still fumbling around with the right terminology. Again appreciate your correction.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found a good explanation to my question.

Per the python ThreadPool link  [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) it says that the ThreadPool does reuse an idle worker thread as Garr Godfrey indicated in his answer.

Looking at the thread names - there are only 5 unique worker thread names and this is because of `max_workers=5` argument.

To explain the duplicate names, the `ThreadPoolExecutor-1_4` has a sleep timer of one, so it finishes up quickly and the worker thread is reused to do the next task, which explains why the worker thread name repeats twice more.

Also notice that `ThreadPoolExecutor-1_1 (4 seconds)`, `ThreadPoolExecutor-1_2 (sleep 3 secs)` and `ThreadPoolExecutor-1_3` (sleeps 2 secs)` worker threads are also re-used by the thread pool (though they're only being re-used once each).